# Pass parameter to dynamic import react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm writing a react app, with mobx and framework7, and using [code splitting](https://reactjs.org/docs/code-splitting.html) in some of my imports, and I haven't found anything on this, but i want to know if there's a way for me to use a variable inside a import, something like this code:

```js
const Slider = import("../parts/Slider").then( Slider =>
    <Slider>
      {
        //sources would be an array of urls
        sources.map( (source, i,) =>
          <div className="slider" key={i}  style={{position:'relative'}}>
            <img className="picture" src={source} alt=""/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </Slider>
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.4.1/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.4.1/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should just use normal import and pass parameters to your React component. Why not to do something like:

```
import Slider from "../parts/Slider";

const SliderComp = ( {sources}, ) =>
    <Slider>
      {
        //sources would be an array of urls
        sources.map( (source, i,) => 
          <div className="slider" key={i}  style={{position:'relative'}}>
            <img className="picture" src={source} alt=""/>
          </div>
        )
      }
    </Slider>

export default SliderComp;
```

and to use it in other file:

```
import Slider from './SliderComp'
...
<Slider sources={arrayOfSources} />
```

Comment: Thanks for you answer! I was trying to avoid static imports, but i suppose it won't improve that much performance for this case.